# can't execute stored procedure in ruby

Tags: sql-server, ruby, stored-procedures

I have written ruby code to connect SQL server , using gem 'odbc' i
could  connect sql server and execute query to select and update tables
but when i tried to call stored procedure it skips the execution and
shows no error
here is my code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'odbc'
odbcdatasource = 'odbcdata'
usrname = 'uname'
pswd = 'paswd'

sqlQuery = "EXEC create_candidates"
ODBC.connect(odbcdatasource,usrname,pswd)do |bd|
results = bd.run(sqlQuery)
end
```

Is there any other method to call stored procedure in ruby code ??

regards

nibin c

Comment: Could you show us your store procedure.Does it Contain any input parameters?

Comment: No krish .. there are no input parameters on my stored procedure

Comment: I could execute this query on sql server management studio but can't execute it through code